# How to properly create AWS IAM OIDC identity provider

Tags: github-actions

Is it possible to create AWS IAM OIDC identity provider in an Organization once then have other accounts in which the AWS IAM role that Github Actions will assume reference the AWS IAM OIDC or we have to create both AWS IAM OIDC identity provider and the AWS IAM role that GitHub Actions will assume in each account that needs it?

```
resource "aws_iam_openid_connect_provider" "github_oidc_github_actions" {
  url = "https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com"

  client_id_list = ["sts.amazonaws.com"]

  thumbprint_list = ["a031c46782e6e6c662c2c87c76da9aa62ccabd8e"]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking if an IAM OIDC identity provider can be set up at the AWS organizational level and then can be used by other AWS accounts under that organization.

If so, that is not possible as IAM identity providers are resources set up per account.